# How can I set fixed width using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to define only fixed width and not height?
Because the `position: fixed;` is not good for me.

I have a Navbar, which it's background not expanding on the full screen on minimized window (because I have an element defined with pixels bigger than the minimized window width, and when I scroll it is not fixed). `position: fixed;` is working for the width of the page, but it's not good for the height.

Comment: can u share the code, or try to give width: 100% or width: 600px like that

Comment: Pretty unclear what you’re asking. Please go read [ask], and [mcve].

Comment: define fixed; fixed in what context: the *absolute size* or the *relative size*, etc? And if relative; then relative to what?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a fixed width you can use examples such as the below:

```
div {
    width: 120px;
}
```

or percentages...

```
div {
    width: 50%;
}
```

In most cases it's best to use max/min width in order to build to responsive design.

If you want the width to not affect the height then it's best to set both accordingly.

see here for other units of measurement you can use within css:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units

Comment: don't recommend w3schools - refer to MDN

Comment: oops, I've updated it now - thanks for the suggestion.